Hibernate Primary Key and Foreign Key Size Mismatch in MySQL
I’m working on a project where I need to set a composite primary key for a Session entity using Hibernate and MySQL. However, when I define the Session entity as follows, Hibernate generates a table with student_id as VARCHAR(255) instead of the expected VARCHAR(36) for a UUID, which causes the following error during schema generation:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Here is my Session entity:
@Entity
@Table(name = "session_table")
public class Session {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CompositeKey compositeKey;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("examId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "exam_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Exam exam;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("studentId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Student student;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date examDate;

    private float mark;
}

And here is the CompositeKey:
@Embeddable
public class CompositeKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "exam_id")
    private int examId;

    @Column(name = "student_id", length = 36)
    private String studentId;  // studentId is a UUID

    // constructors, getters, setters, equals, hashCode
}

Student class implementation:
@Entity

@Table (name="student_table")
public class Student {


    public Student(){}

    @Id
    @Column(name = "student_id", length = 36) 
    private String idStudent;
    private String nameStudent;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Exam> listExams = new ArrayList<>();

    public Student(String nameStudent){
        this.nameStudent = nameStudent;
        this.idStudent = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
    // class methods
}

Problem:
The student_id column should be VARCHAR(36) (since it’s a UUID), but Hibernate is generating VARCHAR(255) (because of the @ManyToOne mapping).
This mismatch causes the SQLSyntaxErrorException because the generated index exceeds MySQL's maximum key length of 1000 bytes.
Question is is there way to have Hibernate generated the primary key considering the CompositeKey not the @ManyToOne Student object or if is there any way to set the student attribute in this part :
@ManyToOne
@MapsId("studentId")  
@JoinColumn(name = "student_id", insertable = false, updatable = false) 
private Student student;

to length 36 instead of 255.

Where and how did you define the Student.student_id column? Relationship mappings pull it from the columns they reference, so verify you have it set as length = 36 there too.

@Chris I have added the implementation of Student class.

If the Student's Student_Id column length is being set to a 36 length correctly, this would appear to be a bug - maybe try the latest versions. Also, why do you have the join column definition set to be insertable=false, updatable=false? This fk reference IS what should set that foreign key/primary key, so it cannot be read-only like this.

@Chris  It was an attempt to solve the issue, when setting it to insertable = false, I wanted it to inherent the length of the primary key/foreign key from the compositeKey attribute (whose length is set to 36), still didn't solve the issue. The only solution I found is to remove the Student and Exam attributes leaving only the CompositeKey object as an attribute. (PS: I am using Hibernate 5.2.11's implementation of JPA)

Other than your version info, I didn't understand your answer. Is the student.student_id a text length of 36? And remove your attempted workarounds from your question, or put them 'after' the main part as description of what you tried, otherwise they muddle things: You cannot have insertable=false on something that maps to your ID - Hibernate is just very.. something.. at giving validation messages. Does the hibernate use the proper type+size for the FK when it is just a normal FK and not in your composite ID?
